# Don't list all users at login with LightDM

Tags: lightdm

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10 and I was wondering if it's possible to not list all the current users and instead require the user to type in their username? My company's IT policies require that users not be listed on login screens.

In Ubuntu 11.04, I was able to do this with the following commands...

```
$ sudo -u gdm gconftool-2 --type boolean --set /apps/gdm/simple-greeter/disable_user_list true
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do this by editing `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` The default contents are just:

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
user-session=ubuntu
```

And you can just add:

```
greeter-hide-users=true
```

To that. For the full list of options, see `/usr/share/doc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` (or look at [this post about lightdm conf](http://hmontoliu.blogspot.com/2011/10/disable-guest-sesson-in-ubuntu-1110.html)).

Comment: In debian buster, `su -` and `nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf ` then Uncomment `greeter-hide-users=false`. `sudo` not work.
[source](https://medium.com/@ehsan.nazim/how-to-make-debian-10-xfces-login-screen-remember-my-username-fe9fb5ab80ef), by Ehsan Nazim

Comment: [I read:](https://github.com/linuxmint/slick-greeter#credit) `List of usernames that are hidden until a special key combination is hit` – so, what _is_ the special key combination then?

Answer (score 3):

Answers suggesting you edit the conf file are **wrong**.

From the [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM):

> LighDM configuration is governed by the `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file, however
>   it's not suppose to be directly edited, instead use:
>
> ```
> lightdm-set-defaults
> ```

I found the file in `/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults`.

You would issue the following on the command line:

```
sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults --hide-users true
```

Comment: While this answer was true at the time of posting, the program lightdm-set-defaults no longer exists. Editing conf files is now the correct method to update the settings. Linux is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

both the above answers didn't work for me (Ubuntu x64 15.04).. the Ubuntu wiki for LightDM works for me, so thought to post here for others who are looking for it although they can too follow the wiki..

source: [What is LightDM?](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM)

as per Ubuntu wiki if we want to override the system configured default session (provided in `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf`) we should make a file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-myconfig.conf` and define our stuffs there...

for example i want to disable listing user accounts, enable manual login at greeting or login screen and disable guest so wrote the following in
 `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-myconfig.conf`

first type: `sudo mkdir /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/` in terminal to create `lightdm.conf.d` folder in `/etc/lightdm/`

then: `sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-myconfig.conf`

and put the following lines:

```
[SeatDefaults]
allow-guest=false
greeter-hide-users=true
greeter-show-manual-login=true
```

now save the file and restart or logout, this is how i get it working.. :)