# Hide user list from logon page in Ubuntu/Xubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, password, username

I'd like to add a little bit more security on my laptop that is running Ubuntu 11.10 with xfce environment. The problem is that once the computer is turned on a list of users is displayed for me to click on and enter the password; I would like to disable this and have it ask for the username and password instead.

Thank you.

Comment: Exact duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/q/68953/32037

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the [LightDM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM) configuration file:

```
gksudo leafpad /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

You may have to substitute `mousepad` for `leafpad` if you're on a newer release.  Add the following two lines to the `[SeatDefaults]` section:

```
greeter-hide-users=true
allow-guest=false
```

You can then restart your system, or just restart lightdm:

```
 sudo restart lightdm
```

Comment: You are most welcome