# Hide users from login screen on Kubuntu 12.10

Tags: kubuntu, users, kdm

This question is a 2 part question (I know there is already a question on GDM):

1. When I create a new user that person shows up on the login screen for Kubuntu 12.10 however I would like to hide that user so he/she doesn't show up.  This has happened for several service type accounts I've created that I want to hide.  The other user case would be a shared computer where I would want my wife's user and my son's user to show up, but my user (the admin account) to be hidden.  So is this possible?
2. Follow up to that question, if there is a way to hide that user from login, how would I go about logging to such user?

Thanks in advance,

Jonathan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a user with id lower than 500. If you already have created one to high number just change id. Edit /etc/password and change id, its the number behind the second :. In my example I chose 666 for user with UserName. Change Username the one you want to hide. And finally make the user own it own files (chown)

```
sudo edit /etc/passwd
sudo chown -R 499 UserName
```

A second option is to edit /etc/lightdm/users.conf, add the user that you want to hide to the list of hidden-users.

To login with the hidden user I think would be difficult, or hide all users and let them [type in their username](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68953/dont-list-all-users-at-login-with-lightdm). A workaround I think that would work is to press ctrl-f1 (to f6) login to console and then write

```
startx
```

to start kubuntu would work

Answer (score 2):

To enable manual login (so you can enter the hidden username also):

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "greeter-show-manual-login=true" >> /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf'
```

see this thread: 
http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/10/quickly-enable-root-login-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal-quetzal/