# Ubuntu login history?

Tags: gnome, users, menu, lock-screen, logout

Multiple users have logged into my 14.04 desktop system.  When I want to logout or lock my screen, the drop down menu shows a long list of many of the users who have logged in.  I would really like to remove that user history from the drop down menu.

This list of users is NOT the same list of users [from the lightdm greeter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68953/dont-list-all-users-at-login-with-lightdm), this is the list of users you see in the drop down menu, once you are logged in.  I have already set the lightdm greeter to not show the login history.  That does not affect the lock / switch user menu drop down.  Hope I made myself more clear?

Any suggestions would be a huge smile on my face.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Enter this in the terminal:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session user-show-menu false
```

And then reboot the machine. (In the other thread they suggest to use `unity --replace &` but it's always better to reboot).

Source: [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87649/do-not-display-user-name-in-the-panel)

Comment: For more info read up on man page for gsettings and look through /usr/share/unity folder

Comment: Xieerqi, your solution worked perfectly.  Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: rocker65, Glad I could help ^_^

Comment: Gotta ask.... This works great if I run it from the command line while an X server is running.  I want to run it in my puppet module to change this on many systems, and it is failing because it needs X.  Is there a file that it updates that I can use in my puppet module instead?  I can't figure out what *gconf* file this gsettings changes.

Comment: Probably I won't be able to help in this part, because I've never dealt with puppet module before. I'm running Ubuntu on a personal laptop. Can you execute a batch script on multiple systems ? My only suggestion would be to put that command into script. As for the file, I'm not sure. There's /usr/share/unity/indicators/com.canonical.indicator.session, which is one used in the original command, but that's all i know at this point. I'll let you know if i find anything else